# Retrieve all method names

Tags: c#, reflection

i am trying to get all of my methods in all the classes with reflection. I Here is my code. I can get the class names, but i cant get the method names. How can i do that?

```
string @namespace = "Application.Main";

List<String> methodNames = new List<string>();
List<String> appServiceClasses = new List<string>();
List<Type> returnVal = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                .GetAssemblies()
                                .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                                .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < returnVal.Count; i++)
{
    appServiceClasses.Add(returnVal[i].Name);
}

Type myTypeObj = typeof(appServiceClasses[0]);
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = myTypeObj.GetMethods();

foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
{
    string a = methodInfo.Name;
}
```

Comment: `typeof(appServiceClasses[0])` is this compiling ?

Comment: no its not. İ try a lot of ways, that must be typeof(CLASS) but i have class names as string, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *already* have the type of your classes, why you are getting name of them ? I mean what is the purpose of doing that? you can use those type instances to get your methods.

```
var methods = returnVal.SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods());
```

**Edit:** you can also use a `Dictionary<string, MethodInfo[]>` so you can access the method so of a class with it's name like:

```
var methods = returnVal.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetMethods());

var methodsOfFoo = methods["Foo"];
```

Comment: i need to know which method belongs to which class, but with your way, i can do that i guess, thanks a lot!

Comment: How can i filter the method list as public or private or something else?

Comment: @TamerMemili use `Enumerable.Where` method on the collection of your methods like: `var publicMethods = methods.Where(x => x.IsPublic);`

Comment: BindingFlags get the public and instance methods by default.You need to use `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` if you want to get private methods as well

Comment: i found this way, isnt this better? var methods = returnVal.SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public));

Comment: actually that is the same as `x.GetMethods()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the type name and then use `typeof`. You already have the type:-

```
var appServiceClassTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                                    .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Namespace == ...)
                                    .ToList();

var appServiceClasses = appServiceClassTypes.Select(x => x.Name);

var methodNames = appServiceClassTypes.SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
                                      .Select(x => x.Name)
                                      .ToList();
```

If you don't actually need the `appServiceClasses` collection anywhere, you should just be able to chain those together:-

```
var methodNames = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                           .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                           .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Namespace == ...)
                           .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
                           .Select(x => x.Name)
                           .ToList();
```

You probably want to know which methods belong to which class, though:-

```
var methods = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                       .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Namespace == ...)
                       .Select(x => new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>(
                           x.Name,
                           x.GetMethods().Select(y => y.Name)));
```

or:-

```
var methods = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                       .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Namespace == ...)
                       .ToDictionary(
                           x => x.Name,
                           x => x.GetMethods().Select(y => y.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the type to ask for methods:

```
for (int i = 0; i < returnVal.Count; i++)
{
  appServiceClasses.Add(returnVal[i].Name);
  MethodInfo[] methodInfos = returnVal[i].GetMethods();

  foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
  {
    string a = methodInfo.Name;
  }
}
```